# Await Async : how to get one method completed before the second one starts

Tags: async-await

How to I make the call so that the GetRecords is completed before _reportViewerService.ShowReport starts. Using SignalR the setUi updates a txt field which displays names from part of the result calculated in getRecords, and the rest should be printed in report there after.

(whats happening now is both running the same time, then the report being showed before I see the live update status)

Thanks in advance

```
public async Task ViewReport()
{

  var reportData = await _apiCallExecutor.ExecuteAsync(new GetRecords(queryModel, setUiHooks));
   try
   {
      if (reportData.Count > 0)
      {
        var settings = new ReportSettings();
        settings.ReportPath = "Utilities/SetDeliveryIdByBatchReport";
        settings.ReportTitle = "Set Delivery ID By Batch - Exception Listing";
        settings.DataSources.Add("DeliveryIdExceptionRecords", reportData);
        ReportStatus = "Printing Exception Report...";
        await _reportViewerService.ShowReport(settings);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
     ViewModelState = ViewModelStates.Edit;
   }

   ReportStatus = "Done...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use some kind of "signal" from `GetRecords`, e.g., an `IObservable` or `Task` that completes when the data has arrived.

```
class GetRecords
{
  ...
  public Task Done { get; }
  // or: public IObservable<Unit> Done { get; }
}
```

then:

```
var getRecords = new GetRecords(queryModel, setUiHooks);
var reportData = await _apiCallExecutor.ExecuteAsync(getRecords);
await getRecords.Done;
...
```